# How to strip "http://" from Html5-QRCode output

Tags: javascript, html, qr-code

I'm working with the code from https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode to convert a camera scan into a textfield and noticed the output of the scan adds "http://" as a prefix.
How do I strip the "http://" out of the output? Actual code below.
("..." is to ignore all the non-question related parts of the code.)
Thank you.

```
QR Code: <input type="text" id="QRCode" name="QRCode" value="Please scan the QR code" disabled="disabled"<br/><br/>
...
let outputContainer = document.getElementById('QRCode');
var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
    "qr-reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 });

function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
    if (decodedText !== lastResult) {
        // Handle on success condition with the decoded text or result.
        console.log(`Scan result: ${decodedText}`, decodedResult);
        outputContainer.value = decodedText;
    }
}

html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
```

Tried editing the .js file to no success as there aren't many references to "URL" or "http" -- there are zero references to "http://". Searched the GitHub project page with no results.

Comment: Just a note, the github link is wrong

Comment: Run the returned 'URL' string through a regex.match and remove it.

Comment: @dalelandry For some reason, my brain refuses to decipher things like "(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");". Will you please provide an example of how decodedText as "https://BLAH" can be converted to "BLAH"? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Without a regex you can use the `substring()` method:
`cleanedUp = decodedText.substring(7)`